# Merge one audio file and one image file to create a video with ffmpeg

Tags: image, audio, video, ffmpeg

I first tried:

```
ffmpeg -y -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

but when I uploaded to video sharing websites (bilibili.com), it says "no video track", so I tried:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest output.mp4
```

The file was successfully uploaded, but when I watched it on the website, the image disappeared and it turned grey. I merged 6 videos and only one of them can be normally played back.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problems with your command #2:

- Frame rate is too low. Most players are unable to play 1 fps. Use 10 fps or higher for output, or set input `-framerate` to 10 fps or higher.
- Chroma subsampling. Most players can only play 4:2:0, so use the [format](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) filter to force it to 4:2:0.
- MP3 in MP4. Some players are unable to play MP3 in MP4. For highest compatibility use AAC. `ffmpeg` will choose AAC by default for MP4.
- Faststart (optional). Add `-movflags +faststart` so MP4 can begin playback faster.

Command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 -vf format=yuv420p -r 10 -shortest -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```